# Python - capture all string between start and end of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I capture all the strings into a list given a start and end characters?

Here is what I tried:

```
import re

sequence = "This is start #\n hello word #\n #\n my code#\n this is end"

query = '#\n'
r = re.compile(query)
findall = re.findall(query,sequence)
print(findall)
```

This gives:

```
['#\n', '#\n', '#\n', '#\n']
```

Looking for output like:

```
[' hello word ',' my code']
```

Comment: @jan Using sequence.split('#\n'), gives the values of all the splits. I just start #\n and end #\n. Results in `['This is start ', ' hello word ', ' ', ' my code', ' this is end']`. I am looking for output above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) would be enough:

```
sequence = "This is start #\n hello word #\n #\n my code#\n this is end"

parts = sequence.split("#\n")[1:-1]  # discard 1st and last because it is not between #\n

print(parts)
```

This will give you (the 1st and last part is immediately discarded because it is not *between* `'#\n'`:

```
[' hello word ', ' ', ' my code'] # ' ' is strictly also between two #\n
```

You can clean this up:

```
# remove spaces and "empty" hits if it is only whitespace
mod_parts = [p.strip() for p in parts if p.strip()]

print(mod_parts)
```

to get to:

```
['hello word', 'my code']
```

or in short:

```
shorter = [x.strip() for x in sequence.split("#\n")[1:-1]]
```

Comment: as @noidsirius noticed, this won't work with `s = "This is start #\n hello word #\n DONT SELECT ME #\n my code#\n this is end" `(assuming OP wants this behaviour).  A possible fix could be a simple `s.split("#\n")[1::2]`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would be better to just use the string function `.split()` and pass it `#\n` as what you want to split on. You can check for the length using `s.strip()` and filter out empty lines. If for some reason you don't want the first and last portions, you can use slices `[1:-1]` to remove them.

```
sequence = "This is start #\n hello word #\n #\n my code#\n this is end"
print(sequence.split("#\n"))
# ['This is start ', ' hello word ', ' ', ' my code', ' this is end']

print([s.strip() for s in sequence.split("#\n") if s.strip()])
# ['This is start', 'hello word', 'my code', 'this is end']

print([s.strip() for s in sequence.split("#\n") if s.strip()][1:-1])
# ['hello word', 'my code']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print(re.findall("#\n(.*?)#\n", sequence))
```

The regex is to capture (non-greedily) anything between two `'#\n'`, but never reuse that for next capture. But if you want it as a delimiter (like `split()`, you can try to use lookahead:

```
print(re.findall("#\n(.*?)(?=#\n)", sequence))
```

and in which case the output will be

```
[' hello word ', ' ', ' my code']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3447515/brian-cohan) suggested, you can use `split` function. However, if you consider those start and end patterns like parenthesis, the correct way to find the tokens is:

```
print([s.strip() for s in sequence.split("#\n")][1:-1:2])
```

it simply skips the strings between an end to its following start. For example, if the input is

```
sequence = "This is start #\n hello word #\n BETWEEN END1 AND START2 #\n my code#\n this is end"
```

the term `BETWEEN END1 AND START2` should not be captured; so, the correct output is:

```
['hello word', 'my code']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
#\n([\s\S]+?)#\n
```

As in

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'#\n([\s\S]+?)#\n')

text = """This is start #
 hello word #
 #
 my code#
 this is end"""

matches = rx.findall(text)
print(matches)
```

This yields

```
[' hello word ', ' my code']
```

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/okw9tO/1/).